# Fancybox grouping elements and show arrows

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery

How can I get the arrows on group of elements in markup as

```
<li>
  <a class="fancybox"></a>
</li>
```

Now when

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({arrows: true})
```

no arrows are displayed!

**this is full code**

```
<li>
  <a href="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report1.jpg" class="fancybox">
    <img src="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report1.jpg" /></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report2.jpg" class="fancybox">
    <img src="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report2.jpg" /></a>
</li>    
<li>
  <a href="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report3.jpg" class="fancybox">
    <img src="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report3.jpg" /></a>
</li>    
<li>
  <a href="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/map.jpg" class="fancybox">
    <img src="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/map.jpg" /></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the same `rel` attribute to each anchor so they can be part of the same gallery that you can navigate through, like:

```
<li><a rel="group" href="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a rel="group" href="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report2.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report2.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a rel="group" href="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report3.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/report3.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a rel="group" href="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/map.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="/img/ProstorNEW/reports/map.jpg" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the `arrow` option within the defaults.

Have a look at http://fancybox.net/api here are all the options you can provide. You are probably looking for a combination of `showNavArrows` and adding custom buttons to handle the next en previous action

Comment: the fancybox 2.0 now available, where this option specializes

Answer (score 0):

Arrow should be displayed by default. Check image path.

Comment: its working on each element, but there are no arrows in fancybox window to navigate to the next element